# Xamarin Forms : Add view Model To ContentView in collectioveView Issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm  adding a ContentView in a CollectionView ItemTemplate

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">              
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <row:QuestionView Question="{Binding .}" /> <--- Content View
                        </StackLayout>                     
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

My Issue is that I am trying to add another View Model into each Question View but the Binding Context is set as the question object and not the Question View Model and I cant change it

```
public static readonly BindableProperty QuestionProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Question)
              , returnType: typeof(AuditQuestion)
              , declaringType: typeof(AuditCrewDetailsListComponent)
              , defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay
              , propertyChanged: QuestionChanged);


        private static void QuestionChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
 (bindable as QuestionView).BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.QuestionVM; <-- tried this but did not change the BindingContext , bindingContext is set to the Question 

            if(newValue != null)
            {
                ((QuestionVM)(bindable as QuestionView)
                .BindingContext).Question = (Question)newValue; <-- Trying to add the question to the view model(throws Error)
            }
           

        }

 public QuestionView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.QuestionVM;
        }
```

```
public class QuestionVM: BaseViewModel
    {

        public Question question;
      

      
        public QuestionVM() : base()
        {
          


        }

        public Question Question
        {
            get
            {
                return question;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref question, value);
                
            }
        }
       
        }
```

So my goal is to pass the question from the BindableProperty into the
question view model.

I'm new to Xamarin forms so I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do, but QuestionChanged currently doesn't make any sense. You shouldn't need that at all. Describe what you want to show in the list row, for that item or question. Are you trying to switch to a different question? Or what?

Comment: if `QuestionVM` contains nothing but.a `Question` the VM doesn't really serve much purpose.  You could just get rid of it.  Or you could just create a `QuestionVM` in the constructor of `QuestionView` using the `Question` property.  If you're new to XF I would probably simplify this a lot and not try to use a separate view or bindable properties.  Just make it work, then you can refactor it later to use MVVM.

Comment: If your goal is to change the appearance of one question, then use [Data Template Selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector). Have a property in `Question` that changes which template the selector loads. For example, you could have a `bool` that selects between two templates.

Comment: So the question object has a list of options , i want to have a selectedOption in the QuestionVM, I am just trying to pass the question from the BindableProperty into the view model

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .